# Validity and precedent of considering the real number line as a circle where positive infinity and negative infinity are the same number

Tags: reference-request, real-numbers, infinity, number-line

It occurred to me that there are some situations (e.g. division by 0 and the tan function) where the two limits of a value, approached from below and above, are negative infinity and positive infinity. And that perhaps instead of viewing negative infinity and positive infinity as two different values/numbers, with the limit not existing in these situations, we could see them as the same number at one end of a circle with zero on one side and positive/negative infinity on the opposite side.
I'm curious as to the utility or validity of this approach, and if it has any precedent.

Comment: Distinguishing between poles with sign changes and poles without sign changes is important for the discussion of a function. So, I cannot see any merit to consider $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to be the same. Perhaps you mean the extended real line. No, it does not make division by $0$ meaningful.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^1\cong S^1\cong\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is meaningful geometrically, as is $\mathbb{C}P^1\cong S^2\cong\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: @Peter, a nonzero divided by $0$ is often taken to be the single unsigned infinity when you have one, as in the projective real line or the Riemann sphere. The OP is right that 1/x extends to a perfectly good/continuous function from the projective line to itself, sending $0$ to $\infty$ and vice versa.

Comment: See @user10354138's answer.  For more information, look up "projective line".  I think user should have written the word "projective" in there, and not just symbols that the OP obviously does not know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this has been considered; the most common name for it which captures its properties and will help you look up more information is the "[projective real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line)" (as opposed to the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) with both $\infty$ and $-\infty$).

But if you don't care about geometry or algebra and just the vague effect this has on shapes, then [topologically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology), this would be the [Alexandroff/one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the real line (as opposed to the [Freudenthal/end compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_%28topology%29)).